# Is there a way we can add a function or variable into an echo? i am trying to echo posts based on categories , i have added the code below :)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, function, echo

Here i have added the code where i am having the problem, i have tried to do a string inside of the echo with function attached but cant seem to figure it out lol. As you can see i am targeting post by cats and wanting to display them when a button is clicked using the ajax function. Thank you guys for your time :)

pHp

```
<?php function groupfunction(){
//////////////////// Group Posts Loop ////////////////////////////
$groupPosts = new WP_Query('cat=75&posts_per_page=4');
if ($groupPosts->have_posts()) :
    
    while($groupPosts->have_posts()) : $groupPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile;
    
    else:
    ?><p>No Content To Display</p>
<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>

<?php function newsfunction(){
//////////////////// News Posts Loop ////////////////////////////
$newsPosts = new WP_Query('cat=76&posts_per_page=9');
if ($newsPosts->have_posts()) :
    
    while($newsPosts->have_posts()) : $newsPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile;
    
    else:
    ?><p>No Content To Display</p>
<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
}
    ?>

<?php function eventsfunction(){ 
//////////////////// Events Posts Loop ////////////////////////////
$eventsPosts = new WP_Query('cat=74&posts_per_page=9');
if ($eventsPosts->have_posts()) :
    
    while($eventsPosts->have_posts()) : $eventsPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile;
    
    else:
    ?><p>No Content To Display</p>
<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Ajax

```
<?php
//////////////////// AJAX ////////////////////////////
function js_swappost() {
    //swap_post_type is a local name for the ajax call and is onlyused in her
    wp_enqueue_script ("swap_post_type", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/ajax.js", array('jquery')) ; 
    //ajax_var is declaring a variable that is available in the client script for accessing data about the Ajax handler
    //nonce is a security featur to prevent injection of Ajax calls
    wp_localize_script('swap_post_type', 'ajax_var', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('swapposttype'))) ;
} 
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "js_swappost") ;

//This is the function to be called when the  Ajax call is made
function swap_post_ajax() {
    //Get the post data type to be shown, defaults to Latest News
    $type = (isset($_POST["postType"])) ? $_POST["postType"] : 'latestNews' ;
    //Get the nonce security code, default to 0
    $nonce =(isset($_POST["nonce"])) ? $_POST["nonce"] : 0 ;
    
    //Check that the security code is correct
    if (wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'swapposttype')) {
        if ($type == "tabnews"){
            $news_events_groups; 
            echo '<p>News</p>';
        }
        else {
            if ($type == "tabevents") {
                $news_events_groups;
                echo '<p>Events</p>';
            }       
            else {
                $news_events_groups;
                echo '<p>Groups</p>';
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Security Alert' ;
    }
    wp_die() ; //Needed to stop WordPress processing normally
}
//This is the code that actually registers the Ajax call wp_ajax is need with the element of 'swap_post_ajax' used to map to the function declared above
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_swap_post_ajax', 'swap_post_ajax') ; //Register the event for logged out users
add_action('wp_ajax_swap_post_ajax', 'swap_post_ajax') ; //Register the event for logged in users
?>
```

Comment: _"i have tried to do a string inside of the echo with function attached"_ - no idea what you are talking about here. I currently find four places in your code that use `echo`, and each one of them echos a simple text literal only.

Comment: "_As you can see..._" I can't seem to see it. Where exactly do you want to echo something?

Comment: I *think* you're talking about the undefined `$news_events_groups` variables. Do you mean you want to call the `groupfunction`, `newsfunction` and `eventsfunction` there in the corresponding `if` statement?

Comment: I think they might rather be asking about absolute basics called variable interpolation and/or string concatenation ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean what I think you mean the answer is no. PHP and Javascript can't talk to eachother directly. They can't exchange variables and functions, because the values and definitions of those variables and functions actually live in different computers' memory sticks. PHP is executed on the server, javascript is executed on the user's device. For all intents and purposes they live in completely seperate countries. The only way they communicate is by sending text and numbers back and forth using POST or GET methods from the client, and prints/echoes from the server.
(this is also why these php responses to ajax requests don't return values, but echo them instead. returning happens in server memory, echoes are directed at the user's device)

edited to add that this is a Good Thing.

o wait. for an actual solution to your problem:
you are using wp_reset_postdata at the end of those functions there which is used after a loop on a post page to restore the main query to it's original state. Since there's no main query as far as ajax  is concerned, that's a weird function to call.